# Convert SQL table to XML with 2 node for each row

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xmlnode, xml-attribute

My MS SQL table has following data

```
    ID    CONTENT     FLAG       TEXT
    ----------------------------------
    1     content1    T          text1
    2     content2    F          text2
    3     content3    T          text2
```

and i want to select values from this table in below format without any root node.

```
<ADDRESS ID="1" FLAG="T">
<FORM CONTENT="content1" TEXT="text1"/>
</ADDRESS>

<ADDRESS ID="2" FLAG="F">
<FORM CONTENT="content2" TEXT="text2"/>
</ADDRESS>

<ADDRESS ID="3" FLAG="T">
<FORM CONTENT="content3" TEXT="text3"/>
</ADDRESS>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a while ago, but - just in case you're still interested in a solution - this would be the query:

```
 DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,CONTENT VARCHAR(100),FLAG VARCHAR(1),TEXT VARCHAR(100));
 INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'content1','T','text1')
,(2,'content2','F','text2')
,(3,'content3','T','text2');

SELECT tbl.ID AS [@ID]
      ,tbl.FLAG AS [@FLAG]
      ,tbl.CONTENT AS [Form/@CONTENT]
      ,tbl.TEXT AS [Form/@Text]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH('ADDRESS') /*,ROOT('Root')*/ --add Root if you need it
```

The Result

```
<ADDRESS ID="1" FLAG="T">
  <Form CONTENT="content1" Text="text1" />
</ADDRESS>
<ADDRESS ID="2" FLAG="F">
  <Form CONTENT="content2" Text="text2" />
</ADDRESS>
<ADDRESS ID="3" FLAG="T">
  <Form CONTENT="content3" Text="text2" />
</ADDRESS>
```