# Nested FOR XML results with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, nested, xmlroot

My MS SQL table has following data

```
ID    CONTENT     UDH         TO       FROM
-------------------------------------------
1     HELLO       1          9812      22
2     HELLO       1          9813      22
3     HELLO       1          9814      22
```

and i want to select values from this table in below format without any root node.

```
<SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
<ADDRESS TO="9812" FROM="22"/>
</SMS>

<SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
<ADDRESS TO="9813" FROM="22"/>
</SMS>

<SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
<ADDRESS TO="9814" FROM="22"/>
</SMS>
```

it is a clear version of what i posted earlier 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149049/convert-sql-table-to-xml-with-2-node-for-each-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this (according your comment):

```
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,CONTENT VARCHAR(100),UDH INT,[TO] INT,[FROM] INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'HELLO',1,9812,22)
,(2,'HELLO',1,9813,22)
,(3,'HELLO',1,9814,22);

SELECT tbl.CONTENT AS [@CONTENT]
      ,tbl.UDH AS [@UDH]
      ,tbl.[TO] AS [ADDRESS/@TO]
      ,tbl.[FROM] AS [ADDRESS/@FROM]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH('SMS')

/* Result
<SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
  <ADDRESS TO="9812" FROM="22" />
</SMS>
<SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
  <ADDRESS TO="9813" FROM="22" />
</SMS>
<SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
  <ADDRESS TO="9814" FROM="22" />
</SMS>
*/
```

Comment: HI, I have writtent it wrong actually it is
    <SMS CONTENT="HELLO" UDH="1">
    <ADDRESS TO="9812" FROM="22"/>
    </SMS>

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, please check the edited code, actually I had closed the Wrong tag earlier

Comment: @RizwanShaikh, I don't understand your comment... What tag is closed earlier and which code should I check? My current answer results exactly the thing you state, doesn't it?